# "Pardon me French"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, etymology

Even though the phrase *pardon my French* is used much more often, I do constantly run across *pardon me French* as well. What's the deal with that? Wikipedia does have an entry on [Pardon my French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardon_my_French), but it doesn't mention the variant with *me* at all. Urban Dictionary has [entries on both variants](http://www.urbandictionary.com/browse.php?character=P&page=51), but sure enough it doesn't bother to explain why they coexist.

It appears to me that *pardon me French* must be the original expression, and *pardon my French* a later variation thereof, since there's no reason why anybody should be willingly tampering with the perfectly fine *my*. Then again, what do I know.

So I'm asking you.

1. Which one is the original phrase?
2. Either way, what's up with the *me* variant? I can't think of any other phrase in contemporary English where *me* is used to mean *my*, can you?

Comment: Shiver me timbers!

Comment: Ah me longin heart for me tu ra lura lura loo.

Comment: The regions where "pardon my French" is common (south England) are the same where *my* -> *me* is also common.  It's not really a variant, it's a sound change shortening /maɪ/ to /mi/

Comment: This is just another way of asking this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247865/non-standard-british-use-of-possessive-me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* reports that *Pardon my French* is an informal phrase used to apologize for swearing.

In some regions, *me* is used to mark ownership; Wiktionary reports the following example:

> And give us back me cigarette!

The use of *me* instead of *my* seems similar to the colloquial use of *me* instead of *I*.

> Me and my friends played a game.

Comment: Actually, *Pardon my French* has nothing to do with French.

Comment: To clarify @mmyers, in *Pardon my French*, ‘French’ means vulgar language or swear words.

Comment: If I would have looked two lines after the line I checked, I would have noticed that. Thank you both.

Comment: I wonder how one should apologize for how he speaks French, then. `:-)`

Comment: In the vulgar circles I frequent 'pardon my French' is often said after breaking wind.

Comment: Nothing to do with "Me and my friends" (see comment above).

Answer (score 8):

English people—especially Londoners—use *me* colloquially in place of *my*.

Comment: It's also quite prominent in Australia, wherever you encounter bogans. As in "give us back me duzza ya bastard!"