# Is it possible to use 'me' as a possessive in English sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, stress, spelling-pronunciations, possessive-determiners

I just found that the word 'me' was used as a possessive in sentences of spoken English, in the movie "Harry Potter":

> "I'm half and half. Me dads a muggle, mum's a witch."

Generally, isn't it proper to use the word "My dad" instead of using "Me dad"?