# What is the agent noun for verbs ending in -y?

Tags: suffixes, agent-noun-suffix, agent-nouns

What is the correct way of spelling it, and what would the rule be for -y verbs like retry.

Is it retryer or retrier?

That is, on -y verbs, is the y kept or substituted by i?

Comment: Ok, why did it get closed? There are other questions similar to this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525800/what-is-the-agent-noun-of-the-verb-mirror
And this is certainly not available in common references

Comment: The question lacks evidence of reasonable research. 'Trier' can probably be easily found in reputable dictionaries. Can 'retryer/retrier'? Agent nouns don't exist for all verbs (consider *_hotfooter / *drip-drier_, and all the verbs now considered acceptable as verbed nouns _beer_ ... *_beerer_ etc.); checking for examples in a dictionary is a first step.